# Change marker color depending on value in database

Tags: php, database, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I have a map and I want to put into it markers.Depending on a value of a column of the database I want to change the color of marker. I have done an attempt but it has errors.Is anybody know how to do it?

```
var green='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
        var yellow='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png';
        var orange='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orangedot.png';
        var red='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);

            <?php if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $value=$row['RSRP'];
            }
        }

            if($value>-90){$icon="green";}
            else if($value<=-90 && $value>=-106){$icon="yellow";}
            else if($value<=-107 && $value>=-120){$icon="orange";}
            else if($value<-120){$icon="red";}
             ?>
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon:yellow
        });
}
```

Comment: You mention errors but don't tell us what those errors are.

Comment: For every marker it shows me this at console
`<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: value in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\site.php</b> on line <b>78</b><br />
<br />`

Comment: It looks like you are populating your $value array without defining it first. Before you start your while statement, or even your if($result->num_rows >0) you should declare the $value variable, e.g. `$value= [];`

Answer (score 1):

Hi use a foreach loop instead and check if the value is set an example:

```
foreach ($sqlResult as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($value)) {
        if($value["color"] > 90){
        $icon ="green";  
        }
    }
}
```

Where "color" is the name of the column which you want to get the value
hope it helps.